# SELECT one entry with two left joins. SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Example
if two products

```
id  name
1   product A
2   product B
```

And for each products I've attributes

```
id product_id value
1  1           1
2  1           2
3  2           3
3  2           4
```

And I need to select products by value of attributes.
I need products which have attributes with 1 AND 2 values.

This query doesn't work:

```
SELECT *
FROM product
LEFT JOIN attribute ON product.id = attribute.product_id
WHERE attribute.value = 1 AND attribute.value = 2;
```

Comment: you need OR not AND in your WHERE clause.

Comment: But that will find products with just 1 or 2, OP asks for products with both 1 AND 2.

Comment: BTW, are you using MySQL or Postgresql, or both? (Tag properly...)

Comment: I need AND in WHERE clause

Comment: Perhaps you mean you want products that have both 1 and 2 attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a group by to find product id's with both 1 and 2 attributes. Select from products where product id found by that group by:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_table
WHERE id IN (select product_id
             from attribute_table
             where value in (1,2)
             group by product_id
             having count(distinct value) = 2)
```

Alternative solution, double join:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_table
  JOIN attribute_table a1 ON product_table.id = a1.product_id
                          AND a1.value = 1
  JOIN attribute_table a2 ON product_table.id = a2.product_id
                          AND a2.value = 2
```

Comment: Thanks, the variant with inner joins helped me.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN attribute a ON p.id = a.product_id
WHERE a.value IN ('1','2')
```

Comment: Attribute conditions in the WHERE clause make the LEFT JOIN work as a regular INNER JOIN. If you really want an outer join, move those conditions to the ON clause! (But I guess you want an inner join...)

Answer (score 3):

To rephrase your question, you really need those products, which has both `1` and `2` *within* the values of their attributes:

```
SELECT    product.*
     -- , array_agg(attribute.value) attribute_values
     -- uncomment the line above, if needed
FROM      product
LEFT JOIN attribute ON product.id = attribute.product_id
GROUP BY  product.id
HAVING    array_agg(attribute.value) @> ARRAY[1, 2];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean values 1 OR 2

```
SELECT *
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN attribute a ON p.id = a.product_id
WHERE a.value IN ('1', '2');
```

Comment: The first one will never return any rows at all because 1 is never eq 2. Attribute conditions in the WHERE clause make the LEFT JOIN work as a regular INNER JOIN. If you really want an outer join, move those conditions to the ON clause! (But I guess you want an inner join...)